# Coldfusion 11 web service response object

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I'm struggling to get CF11 to give me a web service response object with the same set of methods as CF8.

For example, one of the web services used to give me this in CF8:

[image: Response Object returned by CF8]

And this is what I'm getting now in CF11:

[image: Response Object returned by CF11]

As you can see, **they are miles different**!

I've tried to set wsversion="2", but didn't help at all:

```
<cfset wsArgs = {wsversion="2"}>
<cfset ws = createObject("webservice", "http://somewsurl.asmx?wsdl", wsArgs)>
<cfset nvArgs = { foo = "bar" }>
<cfset result = ws.createNameValues(argumentCollection = nvArgs)>
```

Same thing if I try wsversion="2" on cfinvoke:

```
<cfinvoke webservice="#ws#" method="createNameValues" argumentCollection="#nvArgs#" returnVariable="result" wsversion="2"/>
```

Any idea?

Note I'm getting basically the same issue on CF10.

Comment: I'm guessing you are running into the difference between Axis 1.x in C8 and AXIS 2.x in CF 10/11. So I think you need `wsversion=1` instead of `wsversion=2`.

Comment: @CarlVonStetten the answer doesn't help Nick, but I suspect you are right. You would have to dig into the WSDL to know for sure :(

Comment: FYI - it looks like he started with version 1 and moved to version 2. But if he did not specifically set it to version 1 he should try that. By default it might be version 2 in CF 10/11.\

Comment: Yes, CF10/11 default to version 2.

Comment: Damn, you guys are right, it should be version 1!! Somehow I got it into my head that CF8 uses version 2. Thanks it works now.

Comment: @CarlVonStetten - You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Leigh, done and done. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ColdFusion 10 and 11 use Axis 2.0 by default, while previous versions of ColdFusion used Axis 1.0.  If you depend on Axis 1.0 behavior in ColdFusion 10/11, specify `wsversion=1` to force ColdFusion to use Axis 1.0.